# Corrupted .mp4 File from iPhone 4 Weather Balloon Launch

Tags: iphone, mp4

We recently launched a weather balloon into space which used an Apple iPhone 4 as a camera. In any case, though, we have about 8 minutes of corrupted video footage in the form of an .mp4 file (the last 8 minutes of footage, that is. The other ~4-5 hours were completely intact). We believe there must be a way to salvage some video from this file. As such, we would like to ask if anyone can help us salvage this video file. Thank you very much for your time, advice, and/or help.

http://www.mediafire.com/?o00mz0ke2his991

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news! It's repairable.

I ran it through this repair utility:

http://grauonline.de/cmsimple2_6/en/?Solutions:HD_Video_Repair_Utility

I only have the demo version so I could only preview about 3 minutes of the video, but it looks like that tool will work well with your file.